# Exact Differentials

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I just started using Mathematica so my apologies if this is a very basic question. I tried to find related questions on this forum but couldn't, so here goes. I have an equation,

$\quad \quad dp =\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial x}dx + \dfrac{\partial p}{\partial y}dy = P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy$

where I know $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$. Then, is there a way that I could solve for $p$? I found some information on this when $P(x,y)dx + Q(x,y)dy = 0$, but this is not the case in which I am interested.

Comment: Please post at least some minimal but complete definitions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The mathematical procedure for solving this exact differential equation is given, for instance, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation), and in general it can be solved the same way in Mathematica.

Comment: While a line integral is one way to solve this problem, it is not the only way.  The other ways are not ways to answer the question cited as a duplicate.  So I do not think this is a duplicate of the other, although the other method of solution ought to be pointed out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At a simple algebraic calculus level, one could do this:

```
exactQ[{P_, Q_}, {x_, y_}] := D[P, y] == D[Q, x] // Simplify;
exactQ[{P_, Q_, R_}, vars_] := Curl[{P, Q, R}, vars] == {0, 0, 0} // Simplify;
exactSolve[vf_, vars_] /; exactQ[vf, vars] :=
 Fold[#1 + Integrate[#2[[1]] - D[#1, #2[[2]]], #2[[2]]] &,
  0, Transpose[{vf, vars}]]
```

Example:

```
p = Exp[x] Cos[y] + Exp[y] + Sin[x] + y + 2 x
PQ = D[p, {{x, y}}]
(*
  E^y + 2 x + y + E^x Cos[y] + Sin[x]
  {2 + Cos[x] + E^x Cos[y], 1 + E^y - E^x Sin[y]}
*)

exactSolve[PQ, {x, y}]
(*
  E^y + 2 x + y + E^x Cos[y] + Sin[x]
*)
```

Three-dimensional:

```
p2 = Exp[x y] Cos[z] + Sin[x z] - y^2 z
PQR = D[p2, {{x, y, z}}]
(*
  -y^2 z + E^(x y) Cos[z] + Sin[x z]
  { E^(x y) y Cos[z] + z Cos[x z],
    -2 y z + E^(x y) x Cos[z],
    -y^2 + x Cos[x z] - E^(x y) Sin[z]}
*)

exactSolve[PQR, {x, y, z}]
(*
  -y^2 z + E^(x y) Cos[z] + Sin[x z]
*)
```

*Update* - Extension to arbitrary dimensions.

```
Clear[exactQ];
exactQ[vf_List, vars_List] /; Length[vf] == Length[vars] := 
 And @@ Map[Simplify[Curl @@ Transpose[#] == 0] &, 
   Subsets[Transpose[{vf, vars}], {2}]]


vf4 = D[w x y z + Exp[w^2 + x y] z, {{w, x, y, z}}];
exactSolve[vf4, {w, x, y, z}]
(*  (E^(w^2 + x y) + w x y) z  *)
```

Answer (score 9):

The typical solution of such expressions proceeds as in the following example.  Suppose

```
f[x, y] = Exp[x^2 + y^2] Cos[x + y] + x + y^3
(* x + y^3 + E^(x^2 + y^2)*Cos[x + y] *)
```

From these we construct `p` and `q`.

```
p[x, y] = D[f[x, y], x]
(* 1 + 2*E^(x^2 + y^2)*x*Cos[x + y] - E^(x^2 + y^2)*Sin[x + y] *)

q[x, y] = D[f[x, y], y]
(* 3*y^2 + 2*E^(x^2 + y^2)*y*Cos[x + y] - E^(x^2 + y^2)*Sin[x + y] *)
```

From `p` and `q`, we now wish to compute `f`.  This is possible, only if

```
D[p[x, y], y] == D[q[x, y], x]
True
```

and it is.  To proceed, we compute the integrals

```
fx[x, y] = FullSimplify[Integrate[p[x, y], x]] + cy[y]
(* x + E^(x^2 + y^2)*Cos[x + y] + cy[y] *)
```

where `cy[y]`, an arbitrary function of `y`, has been added, because `Integrate` does not do so.  Similarly,

```
fy[x, y] = FullSimplify[Integrate[q[x, y], y]] + cx[x]
(* y^3 + E^(x^2 + y^2)*Cos[x + y] + cx[x] *)
```

To determine `cx[x]` and `cy[y]`, `fx` and `fy` are equated.

```
FullSimplify[fx[x, y] - fy[x, y]] == 0
(* x - y^3 - cx[x] + cy[y] == 0 *)
```

Hence, `cx[x] = x + c` and `cy[y] = y^3 + c`, with `c` an arbitrary constant.  Substituting these into `fx` and `fy` give for both

```
f[x, y] = Exp[x^2 + y^2]*Cos[x + y] + x + y^3 + c
```

as desired.  A more formal but equivalent approach is available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation).

**Addendum**

`DSolve` has become more effective since this question first was posted and now can solve it directly.  For instance, with the sample problem used earlier in  this answer,

```
DSolveValue[
   {D[f[x, y], x] == 1 + 2 E^(x^2 + y^2) x Cos[x + y] - E^(x^2 + y^2) Sin[x + y], 
    D[f[x, y], y] ==  3 y^2 + 2 E^(x^2 + y^2) y Cos[x + y] - E^(x^2 + y^2) Sin[x + y]}, 
    f[x, y], {x, y}] // FullSimplify

(* x + y^3 + C[1] + E^(x^2 + y^2) Cos[x + y] *)
```

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

This should be able to be solved with the DifferentialForms.m package https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/482/. Here is a sample script using one of the above examples:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
<< DifferentialForms`
p1 = Exp[x] Cos[y] + Exp[y] + Sin[x] + y + 2 x
q = d[p1] (*Take exterior derivative*)
p2 = Simplify[HomotopyOperator[q]] (*Find antiderivative*)
r = Simplify[p1 - p2] (*Check p2 is antiderivative for q*)
s = d[r] (*Check r is closed and therefore exact*)
```

We get

```
q = (2 + Cos[x] + E^x Cos[y])dx + (1 + E^y - E^x Sin[y])dy
p2 = -2 + E^y + 2 x + y + E^x Cos[y] + Sin[x]
r = 2
s = 0
```

Comment: HomotopyOperator is almost worth the price of admission for DifferentialForms.m by itself. Integral together with HomotopyOperator definitely are, IMHO.