# Given the u or v of the analytic function f(z), find f(z)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Given the u or v of the analytic function f(z), find f(z):

`z=x+I y`,

`f[z]=u[x,y]+I v[x,y]`

Given
$v=\left[-x+\left(x^2+y^2\right)^{1 / 2}\right]^{1 / 2}, f(0)=0$

Then find `f[z]`.

**First, I get `u[x,y]` by Total derivative method.**

(Cite from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79074/69835)

```
Clear["Global`*"];
exactQ[{P_, Q_}, {x_, y_}] := D[P, y] == D[Q, x] // Simplify;
exactQ[{P_, Q_, R_}, vars_] := 
  Curl[{P, Q, R}, vars] == {0, 0, 0} // Simplify;
exactSolve[vf_, vars_] /; exactQ[vf, vars] := 
 Fold[#1 + Integrate[#2[[1]] - D[#1, #2[[2]]], #2[[2]]] &, 0, 
  Transpose[{vf, vars}]]

v[x_, y_] := (-x + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))^(1/2)

dtu[x_, y_] := {D[v[x, y], y], -D[v[x, y], x]}
u[x, y] = exactSolve[dtu[x, y], {x, y}]
```

(*  $\frac{y}{\sqrt{-x+\sqrt{\mathrm{x}^2+\mathrm{y}^2}}}$  *)

**Then I tried to find f[z], but the result was not completely simplified.** I don't know what caused it and how to modify the code. **The correct answer in the textbook is $f(z)=\sqrt{2 z}$.**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

u[x, y] = y/Sqrt[-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]];

v[x, y] = (-x + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))^(1/2);

f[x, y] = (u[x, y] + c) + I v[x, y] // Simplify
eq = Simplify[f[x, y], {x + I*y == z}] /. z -> 0
sol = Solve[eq == 0, c]
f[x, y] = f[x, y] /. sol[[1]]

expr = Simplify[f[x, y], {x + I*y == z}]
```

(*  $-\frac{{\mathbb{i} z}}{\sqrt{-x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}$  *)

**EDIT**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

u[x, y] = y/Sqrt[-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]];

v[x, y] = (-x + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))^(1/2);

f[x, y] = u[x, y] + c + I v[x, y];
eq = Simplify[f[x, y], {x + I*y == z}] /. z -> 0;
sol = Solve[eq == 0, c];
f[x, y] = f[x, y] /. sol[[1]]

f[z_] := 
  FullSimplify[
   f[x, y] /. {x -> (z + Conjugate[z])/2, 
     y -> (z - Conjugate[z])/(2 I)}, Element[x | y, Reals]];

f[z]
```

(*  -((I z)/Sqrt[Abs[z] - Re[z]])  *)

**But the result `-((I z)/Sqrt[Abs[z] - Re[z]])` cannot be simplified to the textbook result `Sqrt[2 z]`. I did not detect any obvious errors in my code, and it obtained correct results when used on other complex functions. I don't know where the problem is.**

Comment: Since the CR-equation holds on the whole plane except 0, why not just take the value on real or imaginary axis? e.g. `u[x,0]+I v[x,0]`

Comment: It is customary to acknowledge [the source](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79064/exact-differentials/79074#79074) of borrowed code. (Borrowing is welcome, but please cite it.)

Comment: @Lacia Thank you for your suggestion. But this method has achieved correct results in other functions, so I think it should be a simplification problem.

Comment: @Michael E2   I'm very sorry that there was no citation before and it has been edited. 
 Thank you for the reminder and excellent code.

Comment: It's no problem. Thanks for the edit. :)

Comment: You asked "How to simplify `-((I z)/Sqrt[Abs[z] - Re[z]])` to `Sqrt[2 z]`?" This is not true: compare the results of `ComplexPlot[-((I z)/Sqrt[Abs[z] - Re[z]]), {z, -2 - 2*I, 2 + 2*I}]` and `ComplexPlot[Sqrt[2 z], {z, -2 - 2*I, 2 + 2*I}]`.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you for pointing out. However, I did not detect any obvious errors in my code, and my code obtained correct results when used on other complex functions. Very confused, I don't know where the problem is. I think there may be a problem with simplifying the square root of a complex function, but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: @lotus2019: Likely a bug in `FullSimplify`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your code in this block:

```
f[x, y] = (u[x, y] + c) + I v[x, y] // Simplify
eq = Simplify[f[x, y], {x + I*y == z}] /. z -> 0
sol = Solve[eq == 0, c]
f[x, y] = f[x, y] /. sol[[1]]
```

sets the constant `c` to `-((I Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])/Sqrt[-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]])`.  I assume this is not the intended effect, and I think it actually makes your answer wrong (or, perhaps, "more wrong".)  Your real value of $f$, assuming that $c = 0$, should be

```
u[x, y] = y/Sqrt[-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]];
v[x, y] = (-x + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))^(1/2);
f[x_, y_] = (u[x, y] + c) + I v[x, y] // Simplify

f[z_] = f[x, y] /. {x -> 1/2 (z + Conjugate[z]), y -> 1/(2 I) (z - Conjugate[z]), c -> 0}

FullSimplify[f[z]]

(* (I (-z + Abs[z]))/Sqrt[Abs[z] - Re[z]] *)
```

But this is not actually equal to $\sqrt{2z}$ over the entire complex plane, at least as Mathematica defines the square root function:

```
Reduce[f[z] == Sqrt[2 z], z]
(* (Re[z] < 0 && Im[z] >= 0) || (Re[z] >= 0 && Im[z] > 0) *)
```

So, for example, we have

```
ComplexExpand[{f[-I], Sqrt[-2I]}]
(* {-1 + I, 1 - I} *)
```

More generally, it appears that in the complement of the region found above, your $f(z)$ is equal to $-\sqrt{2z}$ instead;  and everywhere on the plane we have $f(z)^2 = 2 z$:

```
FullSimplify[f[z]^2]
(* 2 z *)
```

Plotting out the functions, it also appears that your function is equal to $\sqrt{2z}$ if you define the branch cut to lie on the positive real axis, while Mathematica defines the branch cut to lie on the negative real axis:

```
{ComplexPlot3D[f[z], {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}],
 ComplexPlot3D[Sqrt[2 z], {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}]
```

[image]

This kind of ambiguity is to be expected when dealing with functions with branch cuts.

Comment: This is so clean and clear: wish could give more than+1

Answer (score 3):

This can be done as follows. Starting from your

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
u[x, y] = y/Sqrt[-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]];v[x, y] = (-x + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))^(1/2);
```

, we have

```
FullSimplify[ ComplexExpand[y/Sqrt[-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + 
 I*(-x + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))^(1/2) /. {x -> r*Cos[\[Theta]], 
 y -> r*Sin[\[Theta]]}], Assumptions -> r > 0 && \[Theta] >= 0 && \[Theta] <= Pi]
```

> `Sqrt[2] E^((I \[Theta])/2) Sqrt[r]`

and

```
Sqrt[2] E^((I \[Theta])/2) Sqrt[r] /. {r -> Abs[z], \[Theta] -> Arg[z]}
```

> `Sqrt[2] E^(1/2 I Arg[z]) Sqrt[Abs[z]]`

in the upper complex half-plane. Making use of [the Riemann-Schwarz principle](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Riemann-Schwarz_principle) with the positive ray of the real axis as $\gamma$, we draw the conclusion this is valid in the whole complex plane with the cut along the negative ray of the real axis.

Comment: `FullSimplify[
 ComplexExpand[
  y/Sqrt[-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] + 
    I*(-x + (x^2 + y^2)^(1/2))^(1/2) /. {x -> Abs[z]*Cos[Arg[z]], 
    y -> Abs[z]*Sin[Arg[z]]}], 
 Assumptions -> Abs[z] >= 0 && Arg[z] >= 0 && Arg[z] <= Pi]` results in `Sqrt[2] E^(1/2 I Arg[z]) (z^2)^(1/4)` which is not OK.

Answer (score 2):

By inspection, it is the imaginary part of a function of $z=r e^{i \phi}$. In polar coordinates we identify the radicand as the square of the half angle sine

$$i \sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}=i \sqrt{r-r \cos (\phi )}=i \sqrt{2 r \sin ^2\left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right)}=i \sqrt{2 r} \sin \left(\frac{\phi }{2}\right)=i \Im\left(\sqrt{2 r} e^{\frac{i \phi }{2}}\right)=i \Im\left(\sqrt{2 r e^{i \phi }}=i \Im\left(\sqrt{2 z}\right)\right)$$

Mathematica is not very good in irrational verifying.

I Sqrt[-x + Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] ==
I Sqrt[r - r Cos[[Phi]]] ==
I Sqrt[2 r (Sin[[Phi]/2]^2) ] ==
Sqrt[2 r]  I Sin[[Phi]/2]  ==
I Im[Sqrt[2 r] E^(I [Phi]/2)] == I Im [Sqrt[2 r E^(I [Phi])] ==
I Im[Sqrt[2 z]]

The Cauchy-Riemann equations can be integrated, but again without running into irrationals, only if one knows the result. It's therefore, I assume, that the result is given in advance-

```
      ((-Integrate[D[#, x], y] + I #  )^2 &)[Sqrt[
          x - Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]] // Simplify

         -2 (x + I y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think it's more like a mathematical approach, suitable for manual calculation. I am looking for a MMA solution to this problem. @Roland F